# laravel passing data from table to table

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent

so i have a form that input data with `<option>`. the  value is come from one database i provide. ( i can make the value from blade.php but the requirement require it from db). and the form will send the data to the main database. i've already make the view and the `<option>` work. but the trouble comes when i want to submit the data to the main database.

-the main db = **blogs** ( target column = **'sistem'**)

-the option db = **sistems** ( source column = **'nama'**)

*the goal is the value of **'nama'** passed to the **'sistem'***

this is the view form

```
<form action="/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  // .......
  // .......
          <select name="sistem[]" id="tag_select">
              <option value="0"> Tidak Ada </option>
              @foreach ($sistems as $sistem)
                  <option value="{{$sistem->id}}"> {{$sistem->nama}}</option>
              @endforeach
          </select>
  // .......
  // .......
   </form>
```

this is the store controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
  // .........
  // .........
  $request -> sistem = array_unique(array_diff($request->sistem, [0]));
  $blog -> sistem      = $request -> sistem;
  // .........
  // .........
  $blog -> save();
}
```

Comment: Have you done $blog->save()?

Comment: i did. sorry i dont write it down. i symbolized it with (//............).i'll edit it.

Comment: what about fillable fields on the model?

Answer (score 1):

Like above and also are you shure that action "/" points to store method?

Comment: yes it is. i already make the form works before, but the trouble come when i added the option feature.

Answer (score 0):

The `save()` method will save the changes that you make to your Eloquent model. Also you shouldn't need to edit the `$request` object to achieve the required result here.

Additionally you will need to ensure that this property on your model can be mass assigned (either in the `$fillable` array or excluded from the `$guarded` array on the `$blog` model).

```
$blog->sistem = array_unique(array_diff($request->sistem, [0]));
$blog->save();
```

Comment: i already did the save(). sorry i dont write it down. i symbolized it with (//............).i'll edit it. also, when i try your suggestion, the result is Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array, string given, called in C:/...../vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\Grammar.php on line 869

Comment: It could be dependent on what you are passing into `array_diff()` through the request. To be honest I'd be doing what you are doing with collections instead for ease of use. E.g.
`collect($request->sistem)->filter(function ($item, $key) { return $item !== 0 })->unique()->toArray();`. You should also check fillable fields on the model as this is likely to be where your original problem lies.

Answer (score 0):

I will show how i store things via post method and it works for me, but you must know that I am noob. Sory if what i writting is obvious for you, but cant do anything more :)

```
 public function store(request $request)
{
    $this->validatePost();
    $post = new Post(request(
        ['title', 'excerpt','deadline']
    ));
    $post->save();
    return redirect(route('admin.posts'));
}
```